# Bootstrap Progress Bar with Apps Script Variable

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, bootstrap-4

I have this Google Sheet cell counter in Apps Script and I don't know how to set the bootstrap progress bar with the "percentage" variable.

**GS**

```
function cellCounter() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var cells = 0;
  sheets.forEach(function(sheet){
    cells = cells + sheet.getMaxRows() * sheet.getMaxColumns();
  });
  var division = cells/10000000*100;
  var percentage = +division.toFixed(0);
  return ( " Cada documento de Google Sheets tiene capacidad para diez millones de celdas. Has usado el <strong>" + percentage + "%</strong> del total con <strong>" + cells + " celdas</strong>." );
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: To know where you stand, how do you connect the GS and HTML files at all? Would you like to set the percentage when you generate / evaluate you [HTML template](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template) or later on, when returning from a GS fucntion called from client-side with [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run?hl=en).

Comment: Files are connected with function doGet() {return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");} in the .gs file. The bar is in the sidebar of my Apps Script Addon so I want the bar to be updated automatically everytime I open the Addon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use [Force-printing scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets)

- This allows you to pass Apps Script variables into your html syntax with `<?!= ... ?>`
- For this, the variable to be passed must be declared globally

**Sample for a Webapp (please adapt it to your dialog as needed):**

**GS**

```js
  let size;
  
  function doGet() {
    size = cellCounter();
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("html.html").evaluate();
  }
  
  function cellCounter() {
  
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    var cells = 0;
    sheets.forEach(function(sheet){
      cells = cells + sheet.getMaxRows() * sheet.getMaxColumns();
    });
    var division = cells/10000000*100;
    var percentage = +division.toFixed(0);
    return percentage;
  }
```

**html.html:**

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <?!= size ?>%">Hello </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The progressbar is not getting any value (it's at 0). I've changed the HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("html.html") with the name of my main html page, and I think it's the only part that i have to change, but it's not working right now.